# How to use ack to search for file name

Tags: command-line, find, grep, ack

I have started using ack which is much faster than grep. However using ack I want to search for file name rather than file contents. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the right tool for the right job. If you want to search for filename, use 'find':

```
$ # search for all *.txt file in current directory
$ find . -iname "*.txt"
```

Comment: very true. "once you hold a hammer in your hand everything starts to look like a nail" :)

Comment: Well, ack (and grep) are nicer because you don't have to be explicit about regexes unless you want to. I usually just do a `find . | ack whatev.ext`

Comment: This works for finding directories as well.

Comment: find and ack behave differently since ack filters out a lot of results by default (contents of version control directories, compiled objects in a source repository) that would be included by find.  The best hammer depends on the results you want.

Comment: Actually, it's apparently [kind of tricky](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/84039/77539) to get ack version 2 to behave like find.

Comment: This is not answering the question...

Answer (score 25):

```
ack -g REGEX
```

Print files where the relative path + filename matches REGEX

Comment: add `[^/]*$` to your REGEX to search in the filename only

Answer (score 9):

I agree it makes sense to use find if you're just searching for *.txt files.  However, ack has powerful file-type detectiong features, so you can use

```
ack -f --perl
```

which will find all the Perl files, based on both the filename (*.pm, *.pl, *.t and *.pod) and the shebang line.

Answer (score 1):

You can do :

```
ack -f | ack "filename.ext"
```